# Angular dev bulild strips/removes Parameters before hash from URL

Tags: angular, hash, router

I am researching a problem I have since nearly two weeks now.

using: angular 5.x + webpack 3.x + `useHash: true`

If I build my project in development mode (or just starting webpack-dev-server), Angular Router removes my Parameters BEFORE the hash. I thought that Angular is only caring about the /#/.. and behind.

Example:

http://localhost:3004/?foo=bar#/my/url/zQFiwsoKPUG081lzrJODqw

get's manipulated by angular (or webpack?) and before the app is visible in the browser it's getting replaced(?) by:

http://localhost:3004/#/my/url/zQFiwsoKPUG081lzrJODqw

Where is my `?foo=bar` gone?

This foo parameter has nothing to do with angular, but can be GA tracking params from mailing links or something like this.

If I am running production build, nothing happens.. the parameter stays.

Do you have any idea, why this happens? I am happy for any hints..

Comment: This is how we excute queries. '#/startpage?Foo=bar'.
The hash is generated by the routing hash and will remove your query by default. Not sure how it works it just does it.

Comment: That's strange, because we used it like this in the angularJS version too. For angular 5+ it's working with params before hash for production build (aot) on live and staging (running inside an CMS System). But with Dev Build (aot or not) it does not work. Thougth it's fixable